Undirected graph with coloring
Recall that, given an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$, a k-coloring (of the vertices of G) is a function $C : V→ [k],$ where $[k] = \{0, . . . , k − 1\}.$ Such
a coloring C is legal if it holds that for every $(u, v) \in E$, it holds that $C(u) \neq C(v)$. We define the following languages,
$\text{COLORING} = \{\langle G, k \rangle: \text{ exists a legal k-coloring for G} \}$
$\text{Exact-COLORING} = \{\langle G, k \rangle: \text{ k is minimal s.t. $\langle G, k \rangle \in \text{COLORING}$} \}$
Is it possible to show that $\text{Exact-COLORING}\in {\text{$P^{SAT}$}}?$

Since $\mathsf{COLORING}\in\mathsf{NP}$ (proof left to you), there is a poly-reduction from $\mathsf{COLORING}$ to $\mathsf{SAT}$ (using Cook-Levin theorem).
Let $f$ be the polynomial reduction, that is a function such that if $f(\langle G, k\rangle) = \langle \varphi\rangle$ then $G$ has a $k$-coloring if and only if $\varphi$ is satisfiable.
Then the following algorithm proves $\mathsf{Exact\text{-}COLORING}$:
Input: graph G = (V, E), integer k
k_lo = 0
k_hi = |V|
while k_lo + 1 < k_hi:
    k_mid = (k_lo + k_hi) / 2
    if f(G, k_mid) ∈ SAT:
        k_hi = k_mid
    else:
        k_lo = k_mid
return k = k_hi

It has a polynomial complexity ($\log k$ times the complexity of the reduction) and does a polynomial number of calls to the oracle solving $\mathsf{SAT}$.
That proves that $\mathsf{Exact\text{-}COLORING}\in \mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{SAT}}$.
